# What instruments are these?

Tags: synthesizer, sound-design

Can anyone tell what instruments are used in the "Killing the Fairy" song? Specifically at [0:15](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qsf2ixvmGtU&t=0m15s) and [0:47](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qsf2ixvmGtU&t=0m47s)?

I feel like the first one could also be achieved with a synthesizer, but wouldn't know how to do that, so any help in that regard would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The entire clip you provided is performed on a synthesizer which begins with a bowed cello like setting in the lower register accenting the first beat while a pizzicato double bass plays the next 7 beats. This repeats, so by the 3rd time the cello like instrument sounds at 0:15 a melodic element is introduced which might be best described as a combination of harpsichord and bell like tone. At 0:47 a bell like finger piano sound continues this melody.

If you wanted to copy the timbre you might want to start with working with strings and bell like tones. The tone that it ends with is a combination of strings, bell tone, and winds. There are no live acoustic sounds in this clip, it's 100% synth'ed.

Comment: Do you consider samples to be not acoustic? The cello notes and pizzicato bass are almost certainly being generated by physical instruments, recorded into a sampler.